# CSS FAB Button Leaving Background Colour After Transitioning (Only in Safari)

Tags: html, css, safari, floating-action-button

I am currently redesigning [this FAB button](https://codepen.io/kennylwx/pen/RwNyZOr) when I noticed that in Safari, after the transitioning from open to close, it would leave a white background mark.

This is how it works on Safari [after opening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYXBC.png) and [after closing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkCB7.png)

I am stumped. I suspect that it might have to do with the `background-colour`. I have tried changing it, but it turns out it wasn't the case. What is the diagnosis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you plese remove transition: opacity 120ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 1, 1); from you r style

**css**

```
.fab::before {
    content: attr(data-tooltip);
    /*transition: opacity 120ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 1, 1);*/
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    color:#333333;
    right: 26px;
    top: 19%;
    background-color:
    #FFD057;
    font-size: .6em;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    -ms-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    padding: 7px 32px 6px 18px;
    max-width: 200px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for figuring it out the proble. But why was this problem present only Safari? I'd like to learn more about it.

Comment: Maybe cubic-bezier not accepted in safari.. some browsers not take tihs transtion valure @kennylee